# Why do navigation properties have to be public for a proxy to be created?

Tags: entity-framework, poco, proxy-classes

At http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057.aspx I read that all navigation properties for which I would like to have a change tracking proxy need to be `public` and `virtual`. From what I understand, the CLR creates subclasses of my POCOs dynamically, and it re-implements the properties to provide the requested behaviour.

For this I undertand that the property needs to be `virtual`, and that it should have `protected` or higher accesability. However, if I want to use these for convenience within the assemby, but don't want to expose them, I prefer them not to be `public`. Which leads me to two questions.

1. (for my understanding of what is going on) why does the runtime require the properties to be `public` rather than `protected` or `internal`?
2. (for my actual situation) are there any workarounds to hide the navigation property, but still have the change tracking behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties must be public (and virtual) OR protected (and virtual) for proxies to work.

Proxies are not pre defined in your assembly, therefore internal won't work.

Private won't work for obvious reasons (proxies inherit from your classes).

Comment: I could have sworn I tried protected, and it didn't work. I'll come back to this after I tried again

Comment: I have tried it with the POCO generator. It is especially useful for the collection's setters.

Comment: The specific reason it doesn't work is that you cannot override an internal virtual property outside of the assembly, as Danny states.

You can achieve the desired result by marking your property protected internal.

Comment: Please add that you need to configure the protected navigation first. So like HasMany(t => t.ProtectedVirtualNavigationCollection).WithRequred(t => t.Source)